# Using Select-Object with ConvertFrom-Json returns weird results

Tags: json, windows, powershell, serialization, wmi

I'm writing PowerShell code that needs to de/serialize JSON for communication with the GitHub API. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
# Grab the latest release from GitHub
$response = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://api.github.com/repos/jamesqo/Emptify/releases'
$releases = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$latest = $releases[0]
$urls = $latest.assets | Select { $_.browser_download_url }
```

While I'm able to successfully extract the values I need from the JSON after running the snippet, they're stored under some weird property name of `' $_.browser_download_url '`, which appears to be the code inside my `Select` block. For example, here's the output of `$urls | Get-Member`:

```
TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name                      MemberType   Definition
----                      ----------   ----------
Equals                    Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode               Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType                   Method       type GetType()
ToString                  Method       string ToString()
 $_.browser_download_url  NoteProperty System.String  $_.browser_download_url =https://github.com/jamesqo/Emptify/re... # ???
```

And this is the output I get from running `$urls | ConvertTo-Json`:

```
[
    {
        " $_.browser_download_url ":  "https://github.com/jamesqo/Emptify/releases/download/1.0/Emptify.Win32.zip"
    },
    {
        " $_.browser_download_url ":  "https://github.com/jamesqo/Emptify/releases/download/1.0/Emptify.x64.zip"
    }
]
```

Why is this happening, and what can I do to circumvent it? Could it be a bug in `Select` that's causing this?

Comment: should be `$latest.assets | select browser_download_url `

Comment: @Matt Thanks, it worked! You should post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably just a case of mixing syntax by accident. In its simplest form you are to use `Select-Object` to get specified properties of an object or set of objects.

So if you want to have `$urls` be an array of objects with a `browser_download_url` property then you just need to do something like this:

```
$urls = $latest.assets | Select-Object browser_download_url
```

The basic properties you can pull are the results of `Get-Member` however you should have checked that *before* you used select in this case. Output truncated to only show a couple of properties.

```
$latest.assets | gm

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name                 MemberType   Definition                                                                                                                                                 
----                 ----------   ----------                                                                                                                                                 
Equals               Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
browser_download_url NoteProperty System.String browser_download_url=https://github.com/jamesqo/Emptify/releases/download/1.0/Em                                                                                                   
created_at           NoteProperty System.String created_at=2015-11-24T21:43:02Z                                                                                                              
download_count       NoteProperty System.Int32 download_count=0                                                                                                                              
url                  NoteProperty System.String url=https://api.github.com/repos/jamesqo/Emptify/releases/assets/1068007
```

There are reasons to have code *similar* to what you had above. Custom sorting properties and calculated properties. Neither of those are needed here though.